# Recibo un undefined, y mi php no crea el archivo que quiero

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo este php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$ret = [
    'error' => false,  
    'message' => '',   
    'data' => [],      
];

$guardar = (isset($_POST['texto'])) ? $_POST['texto'] : '';
$aFile = (isset($_POST['archivo'])) ? $_POST['archivo'] : '';
$aFolder = (isset($_POST['carpeta'])) ? $_POST['carpeta'] : '';

if(empty($guardar) or empty($aFile) or empty($aFolder)) {
    $ret['error'] = true;
    $ret['message'] = 'Variable no proporcionada';
} else {

    file_put_contents($aFolder.$aFile, $guardar);
    $ret['message'] = 'Creado file';

}

echo json_encode($ret);
```

y lo mando a llamar con esta función Ajax en un javascript:

```
            var encabezados = String("\"Nombre\"\t\"Titulo\"\t\"Correo\"\t\"Mensaje\"\t\"Contestado\"\n" + appendear);

            let postData = new FormData();
            postData.append('texto', encabezados);
            postData.append('archivo', 'Mensajes.tsv');
            postData.append('carpeta', 'Files');

            fetch('comandos/guardaFile.php', {
                method: 'POST',  
                body: postData   
            }).then(function(response) {
                if(response.ok) {
                    return response.json();            
                } else {
                    throw 'Error en respuesta: ' + response.text();
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
                if(result.error) {
                    console.log('Datos no válidos: ' + result.message);
                    return;
                }
                let retor = result.data;
                let objeto = retor[0];
                console.log(objeto['message']);

            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Error en petición AJAX: ' + error);
            });
```

Pero al ejecutarlo recibe en consola un undefined (debería recibir el mensaje de que el archivo fue creado, o de que hubo un error), y al ver en Filezilla la carpeta donde querría que el archivo se crease, no hay nada. Antes de llegar aquí, hubo otra función que me revisó que el archivo no existiera (me aproveché de un ajax similar, y revisé si recibía como error el código 404), por lo que si llega a esta parte es que el archivo no existe.

Comment: Recuerda devolver un _JSON_ en lugar de una cadena: `echo json_encode($ret);` y, en el primer `then()` de la petición `return response.json();`. No tiene caso cambiar lo que ya te había funcionado porque solo quieres recibir el mensaje.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya hice el cambio pero sigo recibiendo undefined, así que debo seguir teniendo un error en el php. Seguiré investigando.

Comment: En tu código PHP no asignas en ningún momento una clave `ok` al array, por tanto, no deberías hacer la verificación así: `if(response.ok) {` podrías usar la clave `error` quizá, en este caso en negativo: `if(!response.error) {` o adaptar mejor la lógica de tu programa.

Comment: Revisa la consola, probablemente hay una advertencia de PHP por ruta incorrecta, que debería ser: `file_put_contents("$aFolder/$aFile", $guardar);` y, por seguridad, te recomendaría validar nombre de carpeta y archivo en PHP, porque sería muy fácil subir cualquier cosa y atacar tu sitio.

Comment: @A.Cedano, la propiedad _ok_ es parte de la respuesta recibida por [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch#Comprobando_que_la_petici%C3%B3n_es_satisfactoria)

Comment: En la consola no me aparece ningún error de ruta

Comment: @Triby gracias por el dato, no conocía ese modo y es la primera vez que veo el uso de `ok`, de hecho, pensé que era una evaluación propia del JSON que se construía en el servidor.

Comment: Recuerda revisar la petición `POST`, en la pestaña _Respuesta_, seguramente habrá ahí algo como `Warning: Unable to open stream...` y provoca que la respuesta no sea un _JSON_ válido. Además, no estás agregando contenido a `$ret['data']`, en todo caso coloca `console.log(result.message);` en lugar de crear la variable `retor`

Comment: @Triby espero que después me pases el dato de cómo validar eso,

Comment: El error no fue error, fue algo que no esperaba. Sigo recibiendo un undefined, pero el archivo se crea, más no donde ni cómo esperaba. Como me gusta ordenar las cosas en todo, tengo una carpeta llamada "comandos" que es donde guardo todos mis php, pues bien, el archivo se creó en esa carpeta, además, en vez de hacer "Folder/Archivo.tsv", hizo "FolderArchivo.tsv", así que, debería buscar cómo hacer que me regrese a la carpeta anterior, luego si me haga el archivo donde quiero (la carpeta en la que lo quiero guardar si existe).

Comment: Ok, no sé qué pasó. Volví a intentario, y de nuevo, no me creó el archivo en ningún lado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendaría no enviar el parámetro *carpeta* si ya sabes dónde vas a guardar los datos, pero aquí vamos con unas pocas validaciones:

- Evitar que archivo o carpeta contengan caracteres que permitan "navegar" en la estructura de tu sitio, como `../`, aunque deberías tener una función para sanear todas las entradas y evitar ataques XSS
- Verificar que existe el directorio
- No permitir extensión en el nombre de archivo, debes asignarla para evitar que suban un script desde el que se pueda acceder a todo el sitio
- Crear correctamente la ruta para guardar el archivo `../` para ir a la carpeta anterior + `$aFolder` + '/' para separar + `$aFile` + extensión

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$ret = [
    'error' => false,  
    'message' => '',   
    'data' => [],      
];

$guardar = (isset($_POST['texto'])) ? $_POST['texto'] : '';
$aFile = (isset($_POST['archivo'])) ? $_POST['archivo'] : '';
$aFolder = (isset($_POST['carpeta'])) ? $_POST['carpeta'] : '';

if(empty($guardar) or empty($aFile) or empty($aFolder)) {
    $ret['error'] = true;
    $ret['message'] = 'Variable no proporcionada';
} elseif(strpos($aFile, '.') !== false || strpos($aFile, '/') !== false
        || strpos($aFolder, '.') !== false || strpos($aFolder, '/') !== false) {
    $ret['error'] = true;
    $ret['message'] = 'Caracteres inválidos en archivo o carpeta';
} elseif(!is_dir("../$aFolder")) {
    $ret['error'] = true;
    $ret['message'] = 'La carpeta destino no existe';
} else {
    // Al guardar asignas la extensión del archivo
    // Agrega otro parámetro para agregar en lugar de sobrescribir
    file_put_contents("../$aFolder/$aFile.tsv", $guardar, FILE_APPEND);
    $ret['message'] = 'Creado file';

}

echo json_encode($ret);
```

Luego, en *Javascript*

```
        var encabezados = String("\"Nombre\"\t\"Titulo\"\t\"Correo\"\t\"Mensaje\"\t\"Contestado\"\n" + appendear);

        let postData = new FormData();
        postData.append('texto', encabezados);
        postData.append('archivo', 'Mensajes'); // Sin extensión
        postData.append('carpeta', 'Files');

        fetch('comandos/guardaFile.php', {
            method: 'POST',  
            body: postData   
        }).then(function(response) {
            if(response.ok) {
                return response.json();            
            } else {
                throw 'Error en respuesta: ' + response.text();
            }
        }).then(function(result) {
            if(result.error) {
                console.log('Datos no válidos: ' + result.message);
                return;
            }
            // Muestras el mensaje directamente, sin otra variable
            console.log(result.message);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error en petición AJAX: ' + error);
        });
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a ti y a todos los de este foro (la versión en español es más agradable). Haré una validación para los archivos, y no pondré más las extensiones. Muchas gracias por tu atención.

Comment: Hice una edición, para que el contenido se agregue al archivo, de lo contrario, solo guardará lo último que le envíes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me había dado cuenta de ese detalle, y ya lo había solucionado, pero conociéndome es probable que tu solución sea mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Por ahi vi un error de sintaxis en la siguiente linea:

```
$rer['message'] = 'Creado file';
```

¿Quisiste decirt "$rer" o "$ret"?

Si a simple vista hay errores de sintaxis probablemente tengas muchos mas, aconsejo que revises bien tu codigo, aplica la de "divide y venceras" primero de lado de PHP verifica que el archivo se cree pasandole datos que tu sepas, verifica que la peticion se este realizando correctamente, y asi paso a paso.

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había dado cuenta de ese error, y ahora veré paso a paso el php porque sigue sin crearme el archivo, y sigo recibiendo el undefined. Ya hice los respectivos cambios en el código de la pregunta. Como en el Ajax si estoy recibiendo una respuesta positiva, debe seguir habiendo un error de sintaxis en el php. Seguiré actualizando lo que me encuentre, muchas gracias.